# Select records from one week previous in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, time

I have data that has a date (Y-m-d H:i:s) column (the type is datetime). I'd like to select all records from 1 week before a date I enter (in the below example: 2011-09-17 00:00:00, but am having some trouble. Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE (DATE(date) = date_sub(date('2011-09-17 00:00:00'), 1 week))
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're missing `INTERVAL` at the front of `1 week`:

```
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE (DATE(date) = date_sub(date('2011-09-17 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 week));
```

Here is a query that I ran that does work for the `DATE_SUB()` part:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_modified > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK);
```

You can use a negative value to go do a "N weeks before given date" query so something like this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_modified > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK);
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE (DATE(date) = date_sub(date('2011-09-17 00:00:00'), INTERVAL -1 week))
```

Comment: thanks. I used the first code you put in (i needed to add "internal" before "1 week".

Comment: thanks.... i can fetch post older than 2 weeks with following query....
SELECT * FROM `mypost` WHERE (DATE(post_date) < date_sub(date(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)) ORDER BY `post_date` ASC

Answer (score 4):

Try this, I like to stick with DATE_ADD and just use a negative value.

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE date >= DATE_ADD('2011-09-17 00:00:00', INTERVAL -1 WEEK)
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to replace the datetime value with NOW() so that I can get data 1week from the current date the query was executed

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_modified  
BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND SYSDATE();
```