# countdown 4 weeks (week by week) back with python/django

Tags: python, django

Could someone know how I can do countdown 4 weeks back with given year and later count start_date and end_date of each week?

This is what I have now:

```
def FourWeeks(year, week):
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    delta_days = d.isoweekday() - 1
    fourweekback = [week - x for x in range(4)]
    for delta_weeks in fourweekback:
        delta = timedelta(days=-delta_days, weeks=delta_weeks)
        weekbeg = datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time(00, 00, 01)) + delta
        delta2 = timedelta(days=6-delta_days, weeks=delta_weeks)
        weekend = datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time(23, 59, 59)) + delta2
    return (fourweekback, weekbeg, weekend)
```

output from this:

```
FourWeeks(2013, 44)
    ([40, 39, 38, 37], datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 7, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 13, 23, 59, 59))
    ([40, 39, 38, 37], datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 30, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 6, 23, 59, 59))
    ([40, 39, 38, 37], datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 23, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 29, 23, 59, 59))
    ([40, 39, 38, 37], datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 16, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 22, 23, 59, 59))
    ([40, 39, 38, 37], datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 16, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 22, 23, 59, 59))
```

and this is what I wanted to achieve:

```
FourWeeks(2013, 44)
    (44, datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 28, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 23, 59, 59))
    (39, datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 23, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 29, 23, 59, 59))
    (38, datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 16, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 22, 23, 59, 59))
    (37, datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 9, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 15, 23, 59, 59))
```

In the next step I like make a query with weekbeg, weekend

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM event WHERE datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s, [weekbeg, weekend] )
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Depending on what DBMS you're using you could move the calculations into the SQL... something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391718/select-records-from-one-week-previous-in-mysql

Comment: Also - your dates don't quite tie up - it'd help if you defined what exactly is a week (starting on a specific day etc...) I can't see how you're getting the 28th Oct there at all

Comment: I will that my week start Monday and end Sunday

Comment: and 44 week of 2013 is start Mon. 28 of October and is end Sun. 3 November and start time is 00:00:01 end time 23:59:59

Comment: So the entirety of the 4 week range should be: `2013-10-07` -> `2013-11-03` ?

Comment: I want countdown week by week in the period 4 weeks from now for example
week 49 Mon 2-12-2013 8-12-2013
week 48 Mon 25-11-2013 1-12-2013
...
week 46 Mon 11-11-2013 17-11-2013

Comment: Ahh okies - I've done the preceding 4 weeks from the date... you should be able to adapt that easily enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to adapt the following (note it uses the 3rd party `dateutil` which is easily installable via pip & co):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, WEEKLY, MO, SU
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def four_weeks(year, week):
    end = datetime(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=week-1, weekday=SU)
    start = end - relativedelta(weeks=4, weekday=MO)
    mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
    for dt in rrule(WEEKLY, start, count=4):
        yield dt.combine(dt, mint), dt.combine(dt + timedelta(days=6), maxt)

for start, end in four_weeks(2013, 44):
    print start, '->', end
```

Output:

```
2013-10-07 00:00:00 -> 2013-10-13 23:59:59.999999
2013-10-14 00:00:00 -> 2013-10-20 23:59:59.999999
2013-10-21 00:00:00 -> 2013-10-27 23:59:59.999999
2013-10-28 00:00:00 -> 2013-11-03 23:59:59.999999
```