# for loop in function

Tags: python, django

My python knowledge is still limited, I don’t know how to execute this function and class in django.
Later instead of print I will make four query loop to raw database, could someone help me to do this correct way?

```
class WeeklyReports(models.Model):
    def FourWeeks(self, year, week):
        self.year = year
        self.week = week
        end = datetime(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=week-1, weekday=SU)
        start = end - relativedelta(weeks=4, weekday=MO)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for dt in rrule(WEEKLY, start, count=4):
            yield dt.combine(dt, mint), dt.combine(dt + timedelta(days=6), maxt)
            for start, end in FourWeeks(year, week):
                print start, end
```

I expected to receive something similar as is here [countdown 4 weeks (week by week) back with python/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444621/countdown-4-weeks-week-by-week-back-with-python-django/20445109#20445109)

But I get this:

```
>>> from weeklyreport.models import WeeklyReports
>>> w = WeeklyReports()
>>> w.FourWeeks(2013, 22)
<generator object FourWeeks at 0x1eb5050>
>>> w.FourWeeks(2013, 22)
<generator object FourWeeks at 0x1eb50a0>
>>> w.FourWeeks(2013, 22)
<generator object FourWeeks at 0x1eb5050>
>>> w.FourWeeks(2013, 22)
<generator object FourWeeks at 0x1eb50a0>
```

This query I will replace later with print:

```
cursor = connections['nocdb'].cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (p.name) AS platform, count(e.id ) AS count FROM event e, lu_platform p WHERE e.platform_id = p.id AND e.sourcetype_id = 1 AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 ) GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY p.name", [start, end] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to write as indentation matters in Python:

```
class WeeklyReports(models.Model):
    def FourWeeks(self, year, week):
        self.year = year
        self.week = week
        end = datetime(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=week-1, weekday=SU)
        start = end - relativedelta(weeks=4, weekday=MO)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for dt in rrule(WEEKLY, start, count=4):
            yield dt.combine(dt, mint), dt.combine(dt + timedelta(days=6), maxt)
```

You can then print by doing:

```
w = WeeklyReports()
for start, end in w.FourWeeks(year, week):
    print start, end
```

What happens now is that `w.FourWeeks(2013, 22)` creates a generator (because you're using the `yield` statement) and you'll only "see" the results when you're using the generator. So you'll only see the results in the last part when running `for start, end in FourWeeks(year, week):`.

Comment: But now I unable to start django shell
reports$ python manage.py shell
/weeklyreport/models.py", line 61, in <module>
    for start, end in FourWeeks(year, week):
NameError: name 'FourWeeks' is not defined

Comment: @user2859660 sorry, now fixed. I think the print statements should go in your view or they can be executed in a shell window.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I posted this question because I was thinking there is a better way to do this. In my view I have working definition.

Comment: It may be worth reading about Python generators as that's what's going on here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators