# MySQL Retrieve data from any previous week

Tags: mysql, date

So, I can do the following to get data from last week.

```
select * from table where week(date)=week(curdate())-1
```

Same for 2 weeks ago. But this fails if the data is in the prior year. What query can I use to get data from n weeks ago regardless of what year the data belongs to.

Edit: The week starts on Sunday 12AM and ends Saturday 11:59PM

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select records from one week previous in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391718/select-records-from-one-week-previous-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

When does a "week" start?  Sunday?  Monday?  The same day of week as today?

Assuming you are happy with the last option, do this:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL $n WEEK
      AND date <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL $n-1 WEEK
```

Example

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE(), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 WEEK, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9-1 WEEK;
+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| CURDATE()  | CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 WEEK | CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9-1 WEEK |
+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2015-02-22 | 2014-12-21                  | 2014-12-28                    |
+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

If you need the week to start on a particular DOW, the query is messier, by further subtracting `INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY`.  And that could be off a little.

The start of the current week (assuming it is Sunday) is `CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY))`.  So, replace `CURDATE()` in the above expression (twice) with this long mess.

Comment: Thanks. Edited question to state that week is anytime between Sunday and Saturday regardless of what today happens to be.

Comment: Added how to start the week at Sunday.  Now my brain hurts.  ;)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I keep getting syntax errors. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Show us the query and the "near '...'" error message.