# How to get data from Mysql between two specific dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to get data from Mysql With Php between 2 dates. 
I am unable to get this..
Here are my Codes.
These Lines are for Date Interval...

```
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$date_to = $today;
$date_to = strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($date_to)); //-7 days for last week. -30 for last week
$date_to = date("d-m-Y", $date_to);
```

Now Here are the Queries Which i am running.. I have two conditions. 1 The Data should be between `$today` and `$date_to` dates. And `assigned` should be equal to `1`. Assigned is a column in Database table `'requests'`.

```
$get_req = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `req_date` between '$today' AND '$date_to' AND `assigned`='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_req);
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $driver_id = $res['assigned_driver_id'];
    $req_id = $res['req_id'];
    $req_title = $res['request_title'];
    $req_price = $res['price'];
    $req_time = $res['request_time'];
    $req_date = $res['req_date'];
    $driver = $res['driver_name'];
}
```

Here i am unable to get my required result. Problem is Only in Date query. I mean in Between Date A to Date B. req_date` between '$today' AND '$date_to'
It works Perfect.

Please advise me what i should do to fix it. I want to get the Records of Past 7 Days only.

Comment: Is `req_date` in `d-m-Y` format? I'd think it would be a date or datetime column in `YYYY-MM-DD` (mysql date format, not PHP `date` codes).

Comment: No i have used same format for Database. (DD-MM-YYYY)

Comment: What is the column type? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html If it is date/datetime you could use some predefined functions to calculate out week, month etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391718/select-records-from-one-week-previous-in-mysql

Comment: Column type is varchar

Comment: So that is why `between` isn't working. As it currently stands mysql just thinks it is text. It should be a `date` or `datetime` column (you will need to update existing data). Maybe this would be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396058/how-to-convert-varchar-to-datetime-format-in-mysql

Comment: I just change query a bit $get_req = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `req_date` between '$date_to' AND '$today' AND `assigned`=1"; Now it is showing records. but not dates which i post. It shows all records.. i want only within date criteria.... Can you help me please.

Comment: As stated with it as varchar mysql doesn't know what you have there is a date. It is just data as far as it is concerned. Change the format and then the data type and it should work.

Comment: Excellent. I just changed Varchar to Date and It is working

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's your DB structure, but you could change your code and do something like:

Your PHP Code

```
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
$today = time();
$date_to = strtotime("-7 days"); //-7 days for last week. -30 for last week
```

And your query:

```
$get_req = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`req_date`) between '$today' AND '$date_to' AND `assigned`='1'";
```

Comment: $date_to is displayed in what structure? ex: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: `strtotime` returns a unix timestamp. Doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. You need to change the query like this.

```
STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%d-%m-%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS
```